# LISP Loop through list

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I have a function "power" which gives me square of the number and the other functions needs to sum every number squared from a list. But it tells me undefined function I and i really can't make it work .

```
(defun power (x)
  (if (numberp x) (* x x) 0)
)
(defun sum (l)
  (loop for i in l do(setq s(+ (power (i)) s)))
    print s)
```

Comment: what is `(ii)`? A function call? Why? What is `print s`? Try to remember how to write function calls in Lisp. Also think what should be a function call and what not.

Comment: what (ii) ? you mean power (i) ? thats a function call .

Comment: But not in Lisp. `power (i)` is not a function call in Lisp. What was the syntax for function calls in Lisp?

Comment: prints s should print the value of s .... but it doesnt work...

Comment: How would you write function calls?

Comment: power i . its works great but it doesnt show the value of s right... it shows its value twice

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

```
CL-USER 12 > (loop for i in '(1 2 3 4) sum (power i))
30

CL-USER 11 > (reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4) :key #'power)
30

CL-USER 14 > (defun sum (l &aux (sum 0))
               (dolist (i l sum)
                 (incf sum (power i))))
SUM

CL-USER 15 > (sum '(1 2 3 4))
30
```

Answer (score 0):

it is giving you that error because you have put `i` in brackets (which the compiler sees as a function call) `...(power (i))...` when it should have been `...(power i)...`. as for the printing just ignore the print statement and
let the function return the value of s as it is as shown here.

```
(defun power (x)
  (if (numberp x) (* x x) 0)
)
(defun sum (l)
  (setq s 0)
  (loop for i in l do
     (setq s (+ (power i) s)))
   s)
```